# Closest Equivalent to Cayley Graphs for Partial Groupoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs, magma

[A [partial groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_groupoid) (half-magma) is a set S equipped with a (single-valued) partial binary operation, as in Bruck's *Survey of Binary Systems*.]

This question may be nonsensical, given that the duality between [Cayley graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) and groups is deeply related to the mutual complete-ness of each structure. If that is the case, perhaps what I am really asking for is a common diagrammatic representation of partial groupoids. Here is a [crappy mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmNaS.png) of what I'd expect from diagrams of half-magmas in the latter case.

If Cayley graphs encode the abstract structure of group, is there a similar type of graphs that encode the abstract structure of a partial groupoid? If there is not, is there some other commonly used diagrammatic representation used for partial groupoids?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there. Please add your question to the post (not just the title) and make it as specific as possible.

Comment: hopefully my last paragraph is more to the point now

Comment: There is so little structure in the concept of a partial groupoid that I cannot imagine anything at all useful to say. All it consists of is a subset $X \subset S \times S$ and a function $f : X \to S$. Think of the case where $S=\mathbb R$, and think of any silly subset $X \subset \mathbb R^2$ and any silly function $f : X \to \mathbb R$. What is there to be said in that level of generality? You can certainly define it's graph $\{(x,y,z) \mid z=f(x,y)\}$, but then what?

Comment: as seen in Bruck's [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-43119-1), there is a surprising amount of technology that we may define on partial groupoids! sub-structures, extensions, chains, morphisms, and (free) generators all make an appearance in the first 8 pages (the rest of the book moves on to higher level structures).